# Use Non WCF Custom Class in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS. The intention is for clients to make a call and receive a custom class, which is not defined as WCF class and is defined in another project/dll. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decorate this custom class with the `[DataContract]` attribute and also all the public properties of it with `[DataMember]` attribute.

You also need both the client and the server to include that project/dll.

Comment: Suppose I have a Parent class Say "A" which is declared as [DataContract]. now I have another child class Say "B" inherited from "A" and it is not declared in [DataContract]. Now I am using the dll of Class "B" in another WCF Class as return type of a function. Will it work? If no then what I have to do?

Comment: No it won't. You need to explicitely decorate B with [DataContract] as well. Alternatively you can change the return type of your function to be A and still return an object of type B (if that works for you).

Comment: My Return type is as "A". So the [DataCotract] is not an inheritable thing. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean "other", what do you want to achieve, what is the disadvantage of this method in your case...

Comment: We have a windows App. Which need a class Reference. but at the runtime according to a parameter the WCF class will decide which Class Reference has to be returned. this classes are simple classes not with [DataContract]. now how to achieve this? without changing the simple classes as they cant be change now.